# paperclip - get global_id for object on other side of polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip for handling image uploading with the asset class being polymorphic. I want to add a value called global_id in the path to the file to prevent everything being dumped into a single directory. Each of the object that will have an asset will have a unique global_id and it appears that paperclip interpolations should handle this.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true

  Paperclip.interpolates :global_path  do |attachment, style|
     # ???
     object.global_id
  end

  has_attached_file :asset, 
    :hash_secret => "jtsomething",
    #:url => "/images/:global_path/:hash_:basename_:style.:extension",
    :path => UPLOAD_PATH + "/:global_path/:hash_:basename_:style.:extension",
    :styles => { :medium => "200x200>", :thumb => "75x75>"  
 }
```

How would I access the global_id on the other side of this relationship?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the other side of the relation as in all other relations, with `assetable` accessor, from the instance of your model :

```
Paperclip.interpolates :global_path  do |attachment, style|
   attachment.instance.assetable.global_id
end
```

assuming that you store your global id in a `global_id` field on your object, or that its model have a method `global_id`